# parsing log4j HTMLLayout logfile with filebeat

Tags: log4j, elastic-stack

i am a newbie in ELK Stack and it could be that my approuch ist wrong.
Im trying to get my logs into Elasticsearch via filebeat>logstash

Logfiles are saved as [Date]log.html.
Looks like this (picture copied from a stackoverflow Thread): [HTMLLayout Log4j picture example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oD4Ox.png)
Im able to read the [Date]log.html and view it via Kibana.
But the way it is displayed is awful. All HTML tags are shown too.

I would like to parse it into the headers like shown in the picture linked above:
- Time
- Thread
- Level
- Category
- Message

Im trying this in the filebeat.yml under filebeat.prospectors without success.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Best regards

Edit:

My filebeat.yml (try and error)

```
filebeat.prospectors:

- input_type: log

  # Paths that should be crawled and fetched. Glob based paths.
  paths:
    - c:\MyDir\log.html
  multiline:
        pattern: '^[[:space:]]'
        negate: false
        match: after  


#----------------------------- Logstash output --------------------------------
output.logstash:
  # The Logstash hosts
  hosts: ["localhost:5044"]
```

Comment: Works like a charm in [LogMX](http://www.logmx.com). Unzip the small software, open your logs. Done.

Comment: Hey xav, thanks for your help. I already have unzipped, Elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat and kibana and all of these already is running (not as a windows service). Im not able to parse a log file which is created by log4j and has a HTMLLayout, so it can be visualized properly by kibana. Am i too vague with my question? Best regards

Comment: part of the Logfile example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/50B0b.png


and how it looks like in kibana: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jm8k1.png

Comment: Im not able to ignore all there <tr>, <br> and <th>. I also would like to group up the stacktrace (all lines beginning with <br>)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to solve this ELK issue, your question is clear enough. I was just suggesting using another log analyzer, that looks simpler and easier to me for this use case

Comment: @xav Ok. thanks for your help. My english is not so well, so i did not understood it as it was mentioned by you :).